# Using $ instead of jQuery in wordpress child theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, themes

$I'm building a wordpress (v. 3.6) site using a child theme of the Twenty Thirteen theme.
My theme's header.php has

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> onResize="resizeHandler();">
```

This is the .js file for the theme, myChildTheme.js:

```
var myStuff;
function resizeHandler() {
    myStuff = jQuery(".stuff");
    console.log("resized, and here's stuff: "+ myStuff);
}
```

In order to use $ instead of "jQuery" I tried the solutions I found on the web. The new myChildTheme.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var myStuff;
    function resizeHandler() {
        myStuff = $(".stuff");
        console.log("resized, and here's stuff: "+ myStuff);
    }
});
```

But then I get a console reference error saying that resizeHandler is not defined.

I have enqueued and registered the theme's scripts and styles in what I believe is the correct way.

functions.php:

```
function myChildTheme_scripts_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'myChildTheme-fonts', myChildTheme_fonts_url(), array(), null );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myChildTheme_scripts_styles' );

function myChildTheme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('myChildTheme_functions', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/myChildTheme.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('isotope_source', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.isotope.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myChildTheme_scripts' );
```

Any hints on how I can get $ to work? Thanks.

Comment: inside `.ready(function($) { ` you can use `$` instead of `jQuery`

Comment: By wrapping your code inside a `document.ready` handler you are reducing the visibility of it.  Nothing outside the handler can see it.  Also, I don't see you trying to use `$` anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to use the correct example with the `$`. I corrected it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach the `resize` event via jQuery itself. Try this:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var myStuff;
    function resizeHandler() {
        myStuff = $(".stuff"); // note $ use here
        console.log("resized, and here's stuff: "+ myStuff);
    }

    $(window).resize(resizeHandler);
});
```

FYI your console will output `resized, and here's stuff: [Object object]` - this is normal.